# swift coreML: prediction function without "options" parameter

Tags: swift, lstm, coreml

In the swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodel), MLModel have two prediction functions

1. func prediction(from: MLFeatureProvider) -> MLFeatureProvider. Predicts output feature values from the given input feature values.
2. func prediction(from: MLFeatureProvider, options: MLPredictionOptions) -> MLFeatureProvider. Predicts output feature values from the given input feature values.

However, in my auto-generated MLModel class, the function with options parameter was not been generated. The following code are my auto-generated predict functions.

```
func prediction(input: coreML_1denses_80iters_k213_2Input) throws -> coreML_1denses_80iters_k213_2Output {
    let outFeatures = try model.prediction(from: input)
    let result = coreML_1denses_80iters_k213_2Output(output1: outFeatures.featureValue(for: "output1")!.multiArrayValue!, lstm_1_h_out: outFeatures.featureValue(for: "lstm_1_h_out")!.multiArrayValue!, lstm_1_c_out: outFeatures.featureValue(for: "lstm_1_c_out")!.multiArrayValue!)
    return result
}

func prediction(input1: MLMultiArray, input2: MLMultiArray, lstm_1_h_in: MLMultiArray?, lstm_1_c_in: MLMultiArray?) throws -> coreML_1denses_80iters_k213_2Output {
    let input_ = coreML_1denses_80iters_k213_2Input(input1: input1, input2: input2, lstm_1_h_in: lstm_1_h_in, lstm_1_c_in: lstm_1_c_in)
    return try self.prediction(input: input_)
}
```

NOTE:
btw, the reason why I want to find the prediction function with "options" parameter is this error message:

```
[coreml] Cannot evaluate a sequence of length 600, which is longer than maximum of 400.
```

And I have found a [solution](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/142#issuecomment-370431204), which is adding a forceCPU Flag in prediction function. The option can be found in [MLPredictionOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlpredictionoptions) called "usesCPUOnly". However, I cannot find a place to put the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add your own prediction method in an `extension` of the auto-generated class (in a different source file).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Matthijs Hollemans. I found the solution. Just write my own extension and override the prediction function like this.

```
func prediction(input: model_1denses_50iters_k213Input) throws -> model_1denses_50iters_k213Output {
    let options = MLPredictionOptions()
    options.usesCPUOnly = true
    let outFeatures = try model.prediction(from: input, options:options)
    let result = model_1denses_50iters_k213Output(output1: outFeatures.featureValue(for: "output1")!.multiArrayValue!, lstm_85_h_out: outFeatures.featureValue(for: "lstm_85_h_out")!.multiArrayValue!, lstm_85_c_out: outFeatures.featureValue(for: "lstm_85_c_out")!.multiArrayValue!)
    return result
}
```